# Multifactor authentication in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I am migrating an application to azure. A part of app uses AD which is already migrated to azure and another part uses sqldb for storing user credentials, roles and permissions. How do I use MFA for sqldb users in azure? Also, Is it possible to show reactUI for users to login and enter MFA?

Thanks
Sach

Answer (score 0):

We have a Microsoft document you can simply follow to get it address. You can directly connect your on-prem SQL server to azure SQL server and get the authentication done by using Azure Active Directory-Universal with MFA

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-mfa-ssms-configure) shows you how to use Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) multi-factor authentication (MFA) with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Azure AD MFA can be used when connecting SSMS or SqlPackage.exe to [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-paas-overview)

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I have 250K users in my app with different roles and permissions. 5K are in azure AD and are authenticated from there. remaining are in SQL server database with custom schema. user names, roles, permissions etc are stored in company specific custom schema. how do I use azure MFA for these users in sql db? another question is that if I can present my custom screens in react app for all users to enter user id and password and MFA? remember, SQL db will moved to azure too

Comment: did you refer the article which i have provided ?

Comment: Rahul, The article shared only is about connecting to a Azure SQL instance via SSMS and at the time do MFA. That doesn't answer the OP's question or requirement. I think the OP expects the 'user identities'  present in their custom DB to be authenticated (including MFA), I don't think it is feasible